# Site not appearing as it does on my computer

Tags: html, css, image

I've made a simple intro website to my site, simply with the buttons 'Media' and 'Share' and a background. On my PC, when I run the site it appears exactly how I would like it to, however when I run it from my site's server (or JSFiddle) the second button doesn't appear. The image is on the server in the correct location.

```
#first {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
#second {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4cg2k722/1/ - Second button doesn't appear. (also appears like this on the server)
https://gyazo.com/6031a7b8c768120b8d7f4adb3e439e20 - How it appears on my PC.

I am using the same browser when I try both.

EDIT: When you load the page from the website, for a split second you see the icon of an unloaded image. before disappearing.

Comment: There are any number of things that could be inherited from any number of classes that would cause your CSS to act funny.  You may need to check the rest of the CSS.

Comment: That is almost all of the css. I have checked the rest, all it is, is a background reference and a statement for the width and height of the page. @durbnpoisn

Comment: You can use your browser's web development tools to check if your image has actually been loaded by the browser. On Chrome it's F12->Sources. If it's not in the list, the CSS isn't the problem.

Comment: I don't see the loaded images on sources :/ @paolo

Comment: Then your image is probably in the wrong location on the server. Or your browser is not permitted to access it. Are there any errors in the development console? EDIT: something like 'failed to load'

Comment: No, but even the images that do load don't appear so it doesn't seem to be that. However, you might be on the right tracks that the location of images may not be accessible.

Comment: Everything loads for me in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t1gLbea7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo in your HTML code. You were missing the closing `"` in your second `<img>` tag. The code should be `<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4ZCrEHW.png">`.

Answer (score 0):

seem that you miss the location of your pictures. http:/asscave.co.uk/wallpaper.jpg do not reach; same for the 2 other pictures http://asscave.co.uk/media.png and http://asscave.co.uk/share.png. 
check the link by copy and paste it in browser seperately. If it appears in your browser it must appear also on your Web page.

try to improve your CSS like this

```
html,body {
  width:100%;  
  height:100%; //no need to specify
  background-image:url(https://i.gyazo.com/6031a7b8c768120b8d7f4adb3e439e20.png)
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#first {
  //set the width and float it 
  margin-top: 5%;

}
#second {
  margin-top: 10%; //why 10px as margin-top?
  //set the width and float it
}
```